# Grails - Where it is stored cache

Tags: grails, caching

I'm using cache in Grails in this way:

```
class Book {
…
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

}

I have many instances of application. I want write REST API for cache, but I don't know where can I find it. All instances are using one database. Is the cache is stored in a database or on the machine where the application stands . If so, where ?

UPDATE. It's my hibernate config for cache

```
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the cache is stored in a database or on the machine where the application stands . If so, where ?

I can't be sure but will assume that you are using Hibernate.  If that is the case, the best answer that I could offer is that it depends on how you have configured your Hibernate 2nd level cache.  There is no way to know that from just looking at the question.

Comment: "Is the cache is stored in a database or on the machine where the application stands . If so, where ?" - The cache will not be stored in a database by default.  It will be on the machine where the application stands and will be in RAM by default.

Comment: Can I get there and see what it is inside?

Comment: Yes.  It isn't clear specifically what you want to see but a starting point is https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html.  You can invoke `getStatistics()` on the session factory which will return a `Statistics` object.  That includes some information about the cache.  You can also invoke the `getSecondLevelCacheStatistics(String)` method on that `Statistics` object to retrieve more stats for a particular region including the entries in that region.  Whatever it is you want to discover, there is a way to get there.